# auto incrementing integer field in Grails

Tags: grails, auto-increment

I have field `int displayOrder = 1` in Grails domain object and would like to increment it by 1 each time the domain object gets saved.

If I have domain object Widget that has one-to-many relationship with Pix, every time Widget gets a new Pix, Pix needs to have displayOrder incremented.

What would be the most prudent way of setting this up? Preferably count should start from 1 to  keep confusion to minimum when someone wants to change the display order. I thought about just duplicating the ID, but then we are possibly looking at displayOrder of 1123, followed by 1169 , etc., so that's not a practical option.

The collection of Pixes belonging to Widget is a sortedSet.

Comment: Can you share some of your code of how you are creating Pix and assigning them to Widget?  It sounds like you're trying to have it so you create a Widget, then the first Pix you associate to it is displayOrder = 1 then the next pix you associate to it is displayOrder = 2.  Is that correct?

Comment: ... yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do a Named Query to get the last max value of the `Pixes`, which would work in scenarios where the display orders have skips and jumps.

```
class Widget {
    static hasMany = [pixes: Pix]
    ...
}
class Pix {
    static belongsTo = [widget: Widget]

    static namedQueries = {
        selectMaxDisplayOrderForWidget { widgetInstance ->
            eq('widget', widgetInstance)
            projections {
                max('displayOrder')
            }
            uniqueResult = true
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
def widget = retrieveOrCreateWidget()
def pix = new Pix(propertyA: "A", ..., displayOrder: Pix.selectMaxDisplayOrderForWidget(widget).list(), widget: widget)
```

If you want to reinitialize the display order numbers after a deleted `Pix` so they are sequential for a `Widget`, per your comment to [@Jarred Olson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8946217/901257), you could do:

```
Pix.findAllByWidgetAndDisplayOrderGreaterThan(widget, deletedPixDisplayOrder, [sort:'displayOrder',order:'asc']).eachWithIndex { pixInstance, idx ->
    pixInstance.displayOrder = deletedPixDisplayOrder + idx
    pixInstance.save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that your code looks something like this then:

```
class Widget {
    static hasMany = [pixes: Pix]
    ...
}
class Pix {
    static belongsTo = [widget: Widget]
    ...
}


def widget = retrieveOrCreateWidget()
def pix = new Pix(propertyA: "A", ..., displayOrder: 1, widget: widget)
pix.save()
widget.addToPixes(pix)
widget.save()
```

You can determine the displayOrder by the size of pixes:

```
def widget = retrieveOrCreateWidget()
def pix = new Pix(propertyA: "A", ..., displayOrder: widget.pixes.size() + 1, widget: widget)
```

EDIT:

If all you need to do is be able to sort a Widget's Pixes by when they were created you could add `dateCreated` to Pix.  This automatically gets set by Grails when a Pix is created.  Then you wouldn't have to increment/decrement the value when you add and delete.

Comment: ... that's what I'm thinking. It also occurred to me that I'll need to adjust the displayOrder for other Pixes when one gets deleted. I'm thinking about just decrementing all values higher the the deleted by 1.